# Changing android app locale via dialog list

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, locale

I am trying to add a language changer to my app due to popular request. I have added a list dialog, and then changed the locale via that as you can see in my code example below. But whenever the user closes and reopens the app or changes the orientation, it reverts back to system language. I have read about Shared Preferences to do this, but i cant understand how to use them to set it? How should i go about this? Below is my related code for this

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {

            myLocale = new Locale(lang);
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (android.R.id.home == item.getItemId()) {
                    finish();

                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_upgrade:
                    Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(
                                    "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nath.thecompletembguidepro"));
                    startActivity(launchNewIntent);
                    return true;
            case R.id.action_language:
                    final CharSequence[] items = { "English", "German", "Spanish",
                                    "Potuguese" };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Change MB Guide Language");
                    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                                    if (pos == 0) {

                                            setLocale("en");
                                    } else if (pos == 1) {

                                            setLocale("de");
                                    } else if (pos == 2) {

                                            setLocale("es");
                                    } else if (pos == 3) {

                                            setLocale("pt");
                                    }

                            }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();

                    return true;
```

here is the full activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected boolean small;
Locale myLocale;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    RateThisApp.onStart(this);
    RateThisApp.showRateDialogIfNeeded(this);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown).duration(700)
            .playOn(findViewById(android.R.id.list));
    YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown).duration(1200)
            .playOn(findViewById(R.id.fabbutton));
}

private FeedbackDialog feedBack;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StartAppSDK.init(this, "105864370", "207677226", new SDKAdPreferences()
            .setAge(10).setGender(Gender.MALE), false);
    LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View v = i.inflate(R.layout.mainactivityfavlayout, null);
    final LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
    root.addView(v);
    setContentView(root);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.newbook);
    small = false;
    final Fab mFab = (Fab) v.findViewById(R.id.fabbutton);
    mFab.setFabDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.ic_action_thumbs_up_down));
    mFab.setFabColor(Color.parseColor("#795548"));
    mFab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (!small) {
                small = true;
                feedBack.show();

            } else {
                small = false;
                feedBack.show();

            }
        }
    });

    boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.br4mmie.minebuilder");
    if (installed) {

        System.out.println("App already installed on your phone");
    } else {
        System.out.println("App is not installed on your phone");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.info));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.mbnotfounderror));
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.download,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent launchNewIntent5 = new Intent(
                                "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.br4mmie.minebuilder"));
                        startActivity(launchNewIntent5);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ignore),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
        alertdialog.show();

    }

    final CardListView list = (CardListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    CardAdapter<Card> adapter = new CardAdapter<Card>(this,
            android.R.color.black);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.add(new CardHeader(getString(R.string.hello)));
    adapter.add(new Card((getString(R.string.recipes)),
            ((getString(R.string.recipesbio)))).setThumbnail(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.bookicon)));
    adapter.add(new Card((getString(R.string.id)),
            ((getString(R.string.idbio)))).setThumbnail(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.idicon)));
    adapter.add(new Card((getString(R.string.mobs)),
            ((getString(R.string.mobsbio)))).setThumbnail(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.mobsicon)));
    adapter.add(new Card((getString(R.string.biomesactitle)),
            ((getString(R.string.biomesbio)))).setThumbnail(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.biomesicon)));
    adapter.add(new Card((getString(R.string.title_activity_ad)),
            ((getString(R.string.adbio)))).setThumbnail(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.miscicon)));
    list.setOnCardClickListener(new CardClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCardClick(int index,
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") CardBase card, View view) {
            Log.i("MBGuide", "Clicked a Button on homepage");
            if (index == 1)
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        RecipeChooserActivity.class));
            if (index == 2)
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        IDActivity.class));
            if (index == 3)
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NewMobsActivity.class));
            if (index == 4)
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        DimensionChooserActivity.class));
            if (index == 5)
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        AdActivity.class));

        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.newbook);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#795548")));

    SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
    tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
    tintManager.setTintColor(Color.parseColor("#5D4037"));
    FeedbackSettings feedbackSettings = new FeedbackSettings();
    feedbackSettings.setText(getString(R.string.feedbackinfo));
    feedbackSettings.setTitle(getString(R.string.feedbacktitle));
    feedbackSettings.setReplyTitle(getString(R.string.feedbacknewmessage));
    feedbackSettings
            .setReplyCloseButtonText(getString(R.string.feedbackclose));
    feedbackSettings
            .setReplyRateButtonText(getString(R.string.feedbackrate));
    feedbackSettings.setBugLabel(getString(R.string.feedbackbug));
    feedbackSettings.setIdeaLabel(getString(R.string.feedbackidea));
    feedbackSettings.setQuestionLabel(getString(R.string.feedbackquestion));
    feedBack = new FeedbackDialog(this, "AF-E0C9EDA7599B-26",
            feedbackSettings);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    feedBack.dismiss();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown).duration(700)
            .playOn(findViewById(android.R.id.list));

}

private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}

public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (android.R.id.home == item.getItemId()) {
        finish();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_upgrade:
        Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nath.thecompletembguidepro"));
        startActivity(launchNewIntent);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_language:
        final CharSequence[] items = { "English", "German", "Spanish",
                "Potuguese" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Change MB Guide Language");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                if (pos == 0) {

                    setLocale("en");
                } else if (pos == 1) {

                    setLocale("de");
                } else if (pos == 2) {

                    setLocale("es");
                } else if (pos == 3) {

                    setLocale("pt");
                }

            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        return true;
    case R.id.action_dlmb:
        Intent launchNewIntent13 = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.br4mmie.minebuilder"));
        startActivity(launchNewIntent13);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_about:
        Intent launchNewIntent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(launchNewIntent3);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_credits:
        Intent launchNewIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                SixthActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent1, 0);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_feedback:
        Intent launchNewIntent11 = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTrNFlR8Mh4&feature=youtu.be"));
        startActivity(launchNewIntent11);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_videohub:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        builder1.setTitle(getString(R.string.mbvhtitle));
        builder1.setMessage(getString(R.string.mbvhdescription));
        builder1.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.download),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent launchNewIntent5 = new Intent(
                                "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nath.mbvideohub"));
                        startActivity(launchNewIntent5);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Requires Network Connection",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        builder1.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertdialog = builder1.create();
        alertdialog.show();
    }
    return false;
}

{
    ;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would make a settings menu with a preferencescreen. Then the user can change his language whenerver he want.

[Settings menu with Preferencescreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Example

```
        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        // EditorObject to store values!
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("Name", mEtxtName.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("Email", mEtxtEmail.getText().toString());


        editor.commit();

    // GET VALUES IN FRAGMENT FROM PREFERENCES.
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mTxtShowEmail.setText(settings.getString("Email", "Default@email.com"));
    mTxtShowName.setText(settings.getString("Name", "Defaultname"));
```

Comment: even with a settings screen, my problem would still persist though. the language is applied until an app restart or orientation change?

Comment: You have to work with SharedPreferences to store and get the value. Its not so difficult.

Comment: I added a example of SharedPreferences ;-)